# Homebrew: fixing doctor warning

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I installed Homebrew in order to install a few packages on my Mac (especially for Git and an older PHP version for Yosemite) and I don't know Homebrew very well.

When I run `brew doctor`, I get the warning below. Though it doesn't seem to be harmful, I have the habit to not let such a warning in place. I found a few topics about such warnings but it seems that each case is different, as well as the solution.

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libbeid.2.7.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeidcardlayer.4.0.7.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeidcommon.1.0.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeidcommon.4.0.7.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeiddialogsQT.4.0.7.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeidgui.1.5.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeidlibjni.2.7.2.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeidlibopensc.2.2.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeidlibopenscinternal.2.2.0.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libbeidpkcs11.4.0.7.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libqt-mt.3.3.8.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libxerces-c-3.1.dylib
```

The brew formulas installed on my Mac:

```
freetype    icu4c       libtool     php54       wget
gettext     jpeg        mtr         unixodbc    zlib
git         libpng      openssl     unrar
```

Does someone know how to solve that? Delete, uninstall, ignore? I don't want to just ignore that and I don't really know what to do.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about those being there.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I looked up the .dylibs and they are apparently support libraries for Belgian government-issued electronic identity cards, in case you were wondering whether its save to delete them.

Comment: Oh, that would explain it all. You're right, we can use and read our ID cards with card readers after installing a special software. I could have reinstalled the drivers if deleted but now I definitely know that I can keep the files. Thanks @Asmus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /usr/local/lib directory is a common place for installers to drop libraries.  For example, my Mac (which has never had brew installed) has the following files in /usr/local/lib.  I recognize some of these as being part of MacFuse, which is (was?) packaged as standard installer, not any fancy package management like brew.

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  247500 Jan  7  2013 libMonoPosixHelper.dylib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   23400 Jan  7  2013 libSFFileMonitor.32.dylib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel   97584 Jan  7  2013 libSFIPC.32.dylib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  201460 Jan  7  2013 libSFIPC.I.dylib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  868012 Jan  7  2013 libSFSyncEngine.I.dylib
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  612920 Jan  7  2013 libSFsqlite3.7.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  790776 Dec 19  2008 libfuse.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     795 Dec 19  2008 libfuse.la
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  790792 Dec 19  2008 libfuse_ino64.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     831 Dec 19  2008 libfuse_ino64.la
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel     102 Oct 22  2012 pkgconfig
```

So to answer your question, you could delete those libraries (or more safely, move them to a different directory) and see what (if anything) breaks.  However, I would recommend leaving well enough alone unless you enjoy hunting down mysterious failures.

Comment: Okay, understood. If it's really nothing to take into account, I'll leave them there.